# Turn off Power LED on Sony VAIO VPCEE23FX

Tags: hardware

Since switching to Ubuntu 15.10 the green LED light on the side of the On/Off button wont switch off after shutdown. Even when the Laptop is unplugged.

I am using a Sony VAIO VPCEE23FX.